Why does the BLE adjustments stop when it receives a some message?
raspberry pi screenshot
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEAdvertising.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>

BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic;
BLEServer *pServer = nullptr;
BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = nullptr;
BLEService *pService;

bool deviceConnected = false;
String cipher = "evry_cipher";  // Expected cipher value
int second_counter = 0;
int minute_counter = 0;
int hours_counter = 0;
String message;
String draft_uuid_1, draft_uuid_2;

#define SERVICE_UUID        "94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "b4b0d6ed-478f-47a1-bdb8-878c639e5890"
#define ALT_SERVICE_UUID    "75f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ff"

class MyServerCallbacks : public BLEServerCallbacks {
    void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
        deviceConnected = true;
    }

    void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
        deviceConnected = false;
    }
};

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    BLEDevice::init("ESP32_Bluetooth");
    pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
    pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());
    pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();
    
    UUIDService(SERVICE_UUID);
}

void UUIDService(const char* uuid) {
    draft_uuid_1 = uuid;
    if (pService) {
        pService->stop();  // Stop the previous service
        pServer->removeService(pService);  // Remove the previous service
    }

    free(pCharacteristic);
    pCharacteristic = nullptr; 
    Serial.println((uintptr_t)pCharacteristic, DEC);
    Serial.println(sizeof(pCharacteristic));

    pService = pServer->createService(draft_uuid_1);

    pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                          CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                          BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
                          BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE
                      );

    pService->start();
    
    pAdvertising->stop();  // Stop previous advertisement
    pAdvertising->removeServiceUUID(draft_uuid_2);  // Remove UUID if it exists
    pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(draft_uuid_1);
    pAdvertising->start();  // Start new advertisement
    draft_uuid_2 = draft_uuid_1;
}

void loop() {
    // Local time adjustments and message expectation displayed on the serial port
    second_counter++;
    if (second_counter == 59) {
        minute_counter++;
        second_counter = 0;
    }
    if (minute_counter == 59) {
        minute_counter = 0;
        hours_counter++;
    }
    if (hours_counter == 59) hours_counter = 0;
    Serial.printf("%d:%d:%d -> Waiting for message...\n", hours_counter, minute_counter, second_counter);
    
    if (deviceConnected) {
        message = pCharacteristic->getValue().c_str();
        if (message.length() > 0) {
            Serial.println("Received: " + message);
            if (message == cipher) {
                Serial.println("+++ Correct message received, starting alternative service +++");
                UUIDService(ALT_SERVICE_UUID);
                delay(7000);  // Wait for 7 seconds

                // Local time counter adjustment
                if (second_counter > 53) minute_counter++; 
                second_counter = (second_counter + 7) % 60;       
                
                // Restart original service
                UUIDService(SERVICE_UUID);  
            } else {
                Serial.println("Wrong message!");
                deviceConnected = false;  // Disconnect
            }
        }
    }
    delay(1000);
}


i'm doing the broadcast below on esp32. on my raspberry pi device, I am sending the message I have defined as evry_cipher via the CHARACTERISTIC_UUID broadcast when the esp32 device is included in the scope.
But in the case where the esp32 is in the coverage area, the ads end after a while and the esp32 cannot see the device.
I have added the result I received on my raspberry pi device in the attach.
I think there is an overflow of memory somewhere. can you help me, please?

It is because by default GATT Server in most GATT enabled peripheral device can accept only one connection. A peripheral stops advertising once central (client) connected to prevent other central from finding the peripheral device and create a second connection. ESP32 supports more than single connection from centra devices but you need manually restart advertising after first connection established. Not sure about Arduino BLE library, but ESP IDF allows to accept few connections.
